# How to pass Action as a parameter without losing reference in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, action

I'm trying to make a progress bar in Unity3D with using C# language.

I have an Action type variable called (task)ProgressCompleted that I'm going to call at the end of the specific function.

You can see in the example code below:

I've tried to declare as a static or non-static. Nothing has changed.

```
public class GooglePlayManager : MonoBehaviour {

    //singleton stuff.

    public static Action initializationProgressCompleted;
    public static Action signInProgressCompleted;

public void Initialize() {
        //do some stuff.

        initializationProgressCompleted?.Invoke();
    }

}

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Action initializationProgressCompleted;

    //singleton stuff.

    #endregion

    private void Start() {
        List<Action> tasks = new List<Action>();
        tasks.Add(GooglePlayManager.initializationProgressCompleted);

        LoadingManager.instance.SetCheckList(tasks);

        GooglePlayManager.instance.Initialize();
    }

}


public class LoadingManager {

   //singleton stuff.

public void SetCheckList(List<Action> tasks) {
        _checkList = new bool[tasks.Count];

        for (int ii = 0; ii < tasks.Count; ii++) {
            tasks[ii] += Progress;
        }
    }

    public void Progress() {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < _checkList.Length; ii++) {
            if (_checkList[ii]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                _checkList[ii] = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        UpdateUI();
    }

}
```

I'm initializing that Action sent as a parameter to another function but it's not working. When I tried to Invoke action the action seems null.

On the other hand I can initialize it directly without sent as a parameter.

Working code is:

```
//ClassA
public static Action initializationProgressCompleted;

public void Initialize() {
        //Complete some tasks.

        initializationProgressCompleted?.Invoke();
    }
```

```
//ClassB
private void Func() {
        ClassA.initializationProgressCompleted += Test;
    }

private void Test() {
   //log message
}
```

Comment: `initializationProgressCompleted` is null when declared and only initialized in the `+= Test` in your working code. Do you set it elsewhere? If so, can you share that code?

Comment: I added whole codes on to post. First calling method is Start.

Comment: @Ruzihm I've added full codes onto post that you can reproduce this problem.

Comment: Your action is null, even calling += on it should error as it isn't initialized anywhere, I would suggest changing your code to this if you are not going to call new on it.  `public static Action initializationProgressCompleted = delegate {};`  This will save it from being null, and will make it so you dont have to check it to see if it is null, and you can just add directly to it.

Comment: There are no error when I call like this. Also, If I don't send as a paremeter, if I use like Working Code section that I've shared on post, It really works without any initialization for variable.

Comment: Do you assign a value to `GooglePlayManager.initializationProgressCompleted` in the inspector?

Comment: Also can you explain what you mean when you say "the action **seems** null" What makes it **seem** null? Are you looking at its value in a debugger?

Comment: @Ruzihm nope, I'm not assigning because it's not possible. I'm not using UnityEvent. Just using general action types of C#. It's not showing in inspector.

Yeah, its value null on debugger.

Comment: Strange. What happens if you do this in `Start`:
`List<Action> tasks = new List<Action>();`
`tasks.Add(GooglePlayManager.initializationProgressCompleted);`
`tasks[0] += LoadingManager.instance.Progress`
`GooglePlayManager.instance.Initialize();` ?

If that gives you the same problem, it probably has something to do with how C# handles lists of actions vs lists of delegates

Comment: also can you confirm that inside `SetChecklist`, `tasks.Count == 1`?

Comment: @Ruzihm it also works. the problem is I'm losing the reference of Action when I send it to a function as a parameter.

Comment: What exactly are you invoking there?

Comment: I guess it's only an example but adding a couple of Lists each one with only one element looks odd. Especially since they all use the same Action. Did you try to use `public static event Action onSomethingHappened` instead? It's an abstraction layer that maybe is a bit saver to use